# programa en NetbeasID13 con conexion a SQlite

Tags: java, netbeans

estoy creando un pograma en netbeansID13 de agregar, insertar, editar y eliminar datos a una base de datos de SQlite, pero me esta arrojando el siguiente error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable code - illegal start of expression
at sistema.empleadosGUI.frmEmpleados.(frmEmpleados.java)
C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\13\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\13\executor-snippets\run.xml:68: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Agradezco mucho me ayuden.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: agrega el codigo de frmEmpleados para ver que es lo que no compila